# Where do I find an iPhone 4's MEID (ebay purchase)?

Tags: iphone, meid

I'm looking to buy and repair an iPhone 4 from eBay, however the seller hasn't stated the status of the MEID. There are pictures posted of the phone and I can see the back, I read in another question similar to mine although specific to an iPad that the number is engraved on the back. Is this also true for the iPhone 4?

Update: The phone doesn't turn on and it does not have the sim tray. Is there any other way to find out the MEID number?

Answer (score 2):

The MEID number (the first 14 digits of the IMEI number) is inscribed on the SIM tray on iPhone 4 phones.

It is also available in Settings -> General -> About as "IMEI" (just ignore the last digit).

More information including photos here: [iOS: How to find the serial number, IMEI, MEID, CDN, and ICCID number](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4061).

Comment: Thanks, but like I mentioned I'm trying to buy the phone of eBay, so I can't actually check the sim tray.

Comment: You could leave a question for the person auctioning the phone. Ask them for the number or to take a photo of the number. Unfortunately the number is inscribed on the back of some iPhones, like the iPhone 5s, but not the iPhone 4 for some reason.